# Изменение цвета шапки меню при прокрутке к блоку с таким же цветом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть страница с блоками разных цветов. Есть меню, по клику на пункт которого, происходит прокрутка к соответствующему блоку.

Как изменить цвет меню на цвет соответствующего блока при прокрутке с помощью JQuery?

В моем примере,меню не меняет цвет на темный,когда происходит прокрутка к секции с классом .black-bg .

Пример реализации [на сайте](https://www.hugoandmarie.com/).

Мой код:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function lpHeader() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('header').addClass('top');
      } else {
        $('header.top').removeClass('top');
      }
    }

    lpHeader();

    $(window).on('load scroll', lpHeader);

    let lpNav = $('header ul');

    lpNav.find('li a').on('click', function(e) {
      let trgtSelector = $(this).attr('href');
      linkTrgt = $(trgtSelector);
      if (linkTrgt.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let offset = linkTrgt.offset().top,
          correction = linkTrgt.attr('data-offset') || 44;
        $('body, html').animate({
          scrollTop: offset - correction
        }, 750);
      }
    });

    window.onscroll = function() {
      let black = $('.black-bg');
      let red = $('.red-bg');
      let navMenu = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (navMenu === 0) {
        $(".header").css({
          "background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
        })
      } else if (navMenu === black.offset().top) {
        $(".header").css({
          "background": "#211f20"
        })
      } else {
        $(".header").css({
          "background": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
        })
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  z-index: 100;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

header ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #211f20;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color .25s, padding .25s;
}

.black-bg {
  background-color: #211f20;
}

.lp-content {
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#slideshow">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<section id="slideshow" class="transp-bg">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="lp-content">
      <div class="lp-slider1 owl-carousel">
        <img src="img/1.JPG" alt="Продукт 1">
        <img src="img/2.JPG" alt="Продукт 2">
        <img src="img/3.JPG" alt="Продукт 3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="portfolio" class="section white-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lp-content">
      <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="portfolio" class="section black-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lp-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="about" class="section red-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lp-content">
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var hT = $('#portfolio').offset().top,
    hH = $('#portfolio').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log((hT - wH), wS);
  if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
    document.getElementById('header').style.background = "blue";
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  z-index: 100;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

header ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #211f20;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color .25s, padding .25s;
}

.black-bg {
  background-color: #211f20;
}

.lp-content {
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#slideshow">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<section id="slideshow" class="transp-bg">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="lp-content">
      <div class="lp-slider1 owl-carousel">
        <img src="img/1.JPG" alt="Продукт 1">
        <img src="img/2.JPG" alt="Продукт 2">
        <img src="img/3.JPG" alt="Продукт 3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="portfolio" class="section white-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lp-content">
      <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="portfolio" class="section black-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lp-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="about" class="section red-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="lp-content">
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

На скорую руку рабочий [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/NarkiShadow/bzxda238/).

При прокрутке до портфолио блок изменит цвет на синий. Цвет можешь задать свой здесь:

```
document.getElementById('header').style.background = "blue";
```

Код можно доработать, чтобы блок возвращал свой цвет при прокрутке вверх, но думаю дальше сам разберешься.